# Top Issues Running ASP.NET app on Mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

Assume I have an ASP.NET MVC app that's not doing anything too fancy (no P/Invoke, no unsafe, etc).

I've considered the idea of running on Mono to support Linux, among other platforms.  I haven't used Mono in a long time. What are the top issues I'm likely to face?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Mono doesn't support Themes
- Mono doesn't have a great GC which means it'll leak more memory and fragment the RAM for you
- Mono doesn't create literal controls the same way .Net does for "empty spaces" which might be a problem

Except for those issues you should mostly be safe for ASP.NET 2.0 as far as I know...

Comment: It is pretty leaky, but as far as I'm able to tell, the Mono team is continually tightening it up, with visible improvements with each .x release.

Comment: This answer is almost 3 years old. Does anyone know whether the issues pointed out here have been addressed yet?

Answer (score 2):

asp.net mvc is targeted for mono 2.6, which is due in [september 2009](http://www.mono-project.com/Roadmap)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned ASP.NET MVC, which runs on .net 3.5, and mono is for framework 2.0.
ScottHansleman wrote blog entry on how to run mvc on 2.0, you can try it. Or use Monorail (or ProMesh.NET) which runs on mono out-of-the-box. They are all MVC frameworks for .net...

Comment: I was hoping to not have to re-write the web portion of my app to support mono. I was hoping I could change a few settings or have a few #IF type things.

Comment: There is a common confusion around .NET 2.0 - 3.5. All these .NET versions (2.0, 3.0, and 3.5) run on top of version 2.0 of the CLR. The only difference is what assemblies you have available. You can either have the assemblies in the GAC or locally in your project. Ancient history now anyway. Mono runs CLR 4.0, includes MVC2, and will run MVC3 if you includes the assemblies in your project.